# ImageMagick negates image after composite Multiply

Tags: image, imagemagick, image-manipulation, imagemagick-convert

The servers where I work upgraded some libraries and now I am getting a weird behaviour out of ImageMagick version 6.7.8-9.

I am using the command

```
composite -compose Multiply bkg.gif overlay.gif output.gif
```

which used to put `overlay.gif`, which is a mostly white image, on top of `bkg.gif`. Now the same thing is happening but `bkg.gif` is negated! I have tried to change from `Multiply`to `Screen`, which, according to the [docs](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/compose/) is the same thing but negates both images and back, but the output was the same.

I have worked around this by negating image `bkg.gif` before doing the same operation but this is not correct and I still have to do this is many scripts that use the same command, so I would like to effectively solve the problem or at least understand it.

Why is this happening? I apologize but I cannot provide the images we are using.

Comment: Try `convert bkg.gif overlay.gif -compose multiply -composite output.gif` - the order and interpretation of the parameters was modified quite considerably...

Comment: @MarkSetchell is correct. Reading the image list before the compose/composite should resolve your issue. If not, please provide examples of expected & actual behavior.

Comment: Thanks but that didn't do the trick.